# returning false gets true and vise versa

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a really strange behavior in one of my methods.

```
 boolean checkMapObjects(Vector2 enemypos, Vector2 playerpos) {
    MapLayers layers = map.getLayers();
    for (int i = 0; i < layers.getCount(); i++) {
        MapLayer layer = layers.get(i);
        if (layer.getName().contains("collision")) {
            for (MapObject obj : layer.getObjects()) {
                Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject) obj).getRectangle();
                float[] vects = {rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getX(), rect.getY() + rect.height,
                        rect.getX() + rect.width, rect.getY() + rect.height, rect.getX() + rect.width, rect.getY()};

                if (Intersector.intersectLinePolygon(enemypos, playerpos, new Polygon(vects)))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

First: the function also uses the last return statement, but thats not the main-issue. What really surpises me is that function inverts the returned value. 
If I call it from an other function like this

```
boolean wtf=checkMapObjects(enemypos, playerpos);
```

`wtf` will always be the inverse value of what SHOULD be returned.
can anyone tell me why?
Just for testing I tried returning true instead of false, but again the value is inverted

Comment: Probably something wrong in your if statement.

Comment: You should debug to understand what exactly is happening. Step through it slowly and check all conditions.

Comment: @noone I did debug it. When doing so wtf always gets the inverse value from the last return of checkMapObjects.

Comment: @Murat K.: don't know which if you mean between the last return and the association of the returned value to wtf is no if statment

Comment: @Aeglasin I don't know. Use the debugger and see what happens.

Comment: @MuratK. : as mentioned, I used the debugger, and between the step where i return false and the assignment to wtf is no other step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, the enemy collided with a wall... because I needed to use Segement not line^^

Answer (score 1):

Rather checking the method, try printing `Intersector.intersectLinePolygon(enemypos, playerpos, new Polygon(vects))` in your method forloop.

I guess it is returning false.

```
boolean currentIntersection=Intersector.intersectLinePolygon(enemypos, playerpos, new Polygon(vects))
```